# looking for a tuturial Angular 6 consuming REST API CRUD

Tags: angular, rest

I am very new to Angular and use the *CLI* in Version 6.

What I am looking for is a tutorial for REST API calls. I found a lot of tutorial but all of them are failing.

Requirement: Post a login (Username/Password) with Headers to the RestAPI (The Password should be MD5-encrypted). I get back an `SessionID` which I have to use in Headers for all other Requests.

What I´m Missing is a Tutorial.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you try [**the documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/http) ?

Comment: Hi, sure but most of them are written like u habe a lot ob experiance in Angular an I could not firgure out my failings...

Comment: If you can't figure out your fallings, then post your fallings, not a question asking for recommendations. Also, if you don't understand your failures, I suggest you learn Angular first, and not just the Http part of it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for ur suggests I will try an aks u again

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try tutorial videos by Gary on [coursetro](https://coursetro.com/).
2. Try [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com)

Also if you can specify which server side technology you willing to use so that can provide more specific links.